# force system to not get new IP from dhcp

Tags: networking, dhclient

I have a VM running Ubuntu that usually after restart it will get a new IP from dhcp, even though the lease is not expired.
For other distros like centos, the VM will keep the same IP after a VM restart.

I tried to look for some dhclient configuration but not sure what to change in this case.

All threads are about how to actually force a new IP lease :)

Comment: So do you **want a new** IP or do you want to **keep** the IP?

Comment: I want to get to keep the same dhcp lease on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old (unanswered) question but since it is ranking in search results I'll add this.
Adding "**critical: true**" to your netplan config should take care of this. It will prevent a dhcp release during interface shutdown.

/etc/netplan/1-netplan.yaml

```
  network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
          eth0:
              dhcp4: true
              critical: true
```

Another option would be to create a reservation in the dhcp server.